# How do I display all products by descending SKU #'s in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, sku

I am trying to display all products on my website in every category by descending SKU #'s. Can't seem to figure out how to do this, any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will give you the collection you want, you may need to add pagination yourself if necessary.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$collection->setOrder('sku', 'DESC');
```

You'll also need to join on any extra attributes with `joinAttribute()`, since the catalog_product database storage follows the EAV pattern.

Comment: Thanks Matt, do you know where I would add the snippet above? which file do I add that to?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help. Go to `Admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage` Attributes find SKU and enable SKU first. Then you have to go `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php.` Find at line 119 and change

```
protected $_direction = 'asc';
```

**Change to**

```
protected $_direction = 'desc';
```